# Filter "orderBy" is not working with variable as array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m trying to use orderBy within a ng-repeat but it´s not working.

This is where I create and populate the array used on the ng-repeat:

```
    for (var k = 0; k < $scope.allUsers.length; k++)
    {
        var score = 
        {
            points: 0,
            headshot: 0,
            winners: 0,
        };

        $scope.currentScore.push(score);
    }
```

And here is where I call it:

```
            <tr ng-repeat="singleScore in currentScore | orderBy: 'points'">
                <td>{{singleScore.points}}</td>
                <td>{{singleScore.headshot}}</td>
                <td>{{singleScore.winners}}</td>
            </tr>
```

This "currentScore" array is changed from time to time in a setInterval function and its values are being correctly updated.. but the orderBy never works.

I know there are a lot of similar questions but almost all are resolved with "you are not using an array".. but I am indeed using an array and it´s still not working. 
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Solved with:

```
$interval($scope.calculateWeekScore, 2000, 10, true, $scope.activeWeek);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setInterval is not called in angular's scope. You will need to call `$scope.apply()`

You can also use angularjs $interval, which is wrapper around setInterval.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: You *should* really use angular's `$timeout`, since it will perform an `apply` automagically

Comment: Okay, so I´m trying to use $timeout... I´ve already added it as a function to the app controller, but it´s not working. It´s simply not being called over time.. The code is edited on the main post.

Comment: Can you make a plunk or fiddle that shows your problem?